# Spring Boot Kafka consumer with multiple types crashing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

It is my understanding, if I have topic1=ClassA, topic2=ClassB in the same process, I need 2 container factories?

My configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, MessageADto> xxxConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MessageADto.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageADto> xxxListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageADto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(xxxConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, MessageBDto> xxx2ConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MessageBDto.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageBDto> xxx2ListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageBDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(xxx2ConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, getKafkaHost());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "xxx");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}
```

In my rest controller class, I have the following listeners (just for POC):

```
@KafkaListener(topics=KafkaTopicConfig.xxx_TOPIC, containerFactory="xxxListenerContainerFactory")
public void xxxListener(MessageADto message) {
    System.out.println(message.getMessage());
}

@KafkaListener(topics=KafkaTopicConfig.xxx2_TOPIC, containerFactory="xxx2ListenerContainerFactory")
public void xxx2Listener(MessageBDto message) {
    System.out.println(message.getMessage() + " : " + message.getCount());
}
```

For the rest controller method, I have to send MessageADto and MessageBDto:

```
        MessageBDto messageBDto = new MessageBDto() {{ setMessage(message.getMessage()); setCount(17); }};
        this.kafkaService.sendMessageB(messageBDto);
        return convertToDto(this.kafkaService.sendMessageA(message).get().getRecordMetadata());
```

This produces an exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition dtms2-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'org.xxx.xxx.controllers.KafkaController$1' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, org.xxx.xxx.dtos]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:125) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:99) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:425) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1268) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3600(Fetcher.java:124) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1492) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1263) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1012) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:905) ~[spring-kafka-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar:2.4.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I don't understand this exception. What does it have to do with my controller class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot / Kafka Json Deserialization - Trusted Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268124/spring-boot-kafka-json-deserialization-trusted-packages)

Comment: @lakshman nope... I tried trusting "*"... just to clarify it seems to be trying to deserialize the CONTROLLER or some anonymous type... very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your controller class to the list of trusted packages

Try adding this to your properties file

`spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*`

If it works then you can figure out what packages you need specifically and replace the * for the package names separated by commas.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. You just saw a few keywords in the error :)... if you look closer at the error: The class 'org.xxx.xxx.controllers.KafkaController$1' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, org.xxx.xxx.dtos]... why is it trying to deserialize the CONTROLLER? It should be serializing MessageBDto. I did find another example after hours of searching where they use the StringDeserializer instead of the JsonDeserializer and that one works as expected... very weird that JsonDeserializer is trying to deserialize the controller...

Comment: I've had this error with the trusted packages before and adding the * nearly always fixed it. Have you tried using the Avro deserialiser - KafkaAvroDeserializer they are really good for mapping the payloads to java objects, the confluent plugin will generate the objects for you based on the schema.

Comment: You are using JsonSerializer on the producer obviously yea?

Comment: My producer is String/Object with JsonSerializer. The sample I found that works uses StringDeserializer for both the key and value on the consumer side. Then in the factory, it uses factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter()); Then it just magically works on the KafkaListeners :). Still no idea why the JsonSerializer was trying to do something with the controller.